# Good way to create model which generates something in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

There is a model `A`, which have some fields in database and some relationships. Action `.create()` for this model doesn't get direct data from user:

- User sets some params at `.new()` form, model generates some data
- Render STEP1
- User modifies this data if he wants and runs final generation.
- Result of final generation stores in database and renders to user.

How this scenario can be applied to MVC and Ruby on Rails?

**Update**
I have a model, named `Route` and `/search` form. At `/search` a user can specify his favorite cities and countries for `Route`.
Some half-random generator selects some suitable cities for user, solving `TSP` and render it on google map.
This is step 1.
User can further edit this pre-route and click "Continue". The generator should find some suitable places in selected cities.
That's all.

Comment: You need to be much much clearer. I've read through your question 3 times now and it still makes no sense whatsoever. Best to supply a specific example and a specific question rather than generalise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/search?langOverride=Ruby&q=wizard&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Comment: I don't need a wizard. It's the simplest thing in all this. I want to know how to organize models and controllers in MVC-style for this generator model.